# How to deal with an Oracle data source in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, oledb, odac

I know, this is a frequently asked question, but I'm not able to solve my problem about how to use an Oracle database in SSIS.

**Oracle data source specs**

[image]

**Configuration**

- I installed `ODTWithODAC121021` & `ODAC121021_x64`
- I defined `tnsNames.ora` to C:...\client_1\network\admin

[image]

```
LANDESK_PP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PPRQU)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = mydomain.com)
    )
  )
```

**Usage**

If I use SQL Developer, the connection works properly, I can execute some queries. Moreover, If I create an `Oracle Provider for OLEDB`connection manager, I can use the preview button too, but the package execution doesnt't work.

[image]
[image]

Now, If I run the package (in 32bit or 64bit debug mode), an error occured because the connection cannot be acquired.

Here is the error :

[image]

```
Error: 0xC020801C at Load LANDESK data, Load LANDESK [108]: Error code SSIS DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Landesk" failed.
```

Any idea to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have run into the 64-bit vs 32-bit driver mess that Microsoft kindly created when they built Windows 64-bit.  Personally I have given up on trying to solve this - I only install 32-bit drivers as the lowest common denominator.

So I would completely uninstall Oracle and reinstall 32-bit drivers only.

Visual Studio and SSMS are 32-bit so they will "see" 32-bit drivers. For 32-bit debug execution in Visual Studio, go to the Project Properties / Debugging and set Run64BitRuntime to False.